# Paste UIPasteboard contents in other apps

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

I used the following code to copy some texts to `UIPasteboard`:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setPersistent:YES];
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"Testing";
```

And I'm able to read the content by:

```
NSLog(@"Pasteboard String: %@", [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string); 
// which gives "Testing"
```

However, I'm unable to retrieve the copied text in any other apps. What is the proper way to copy texts in my App and then paste in other apps?

Using iOS 8.

Comment: You're using the proper method for storing the value, what method are you using to retrieve it? Are you possibly setting the string to nil somewhere else in your code?

Comment: In other apps like Notes App (the system one), I just long hold & wait for the Paste option comes up, which is never shown. I can confirm the string is still copied within my App.

Comment: If the paste option doesn't come up then there is nothing in the general UIPasteboard. Most likely `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"";` is being called somewhere unexpectedly.

Comment: Not sure if it's related: My app is sharing images to Facebook via native Facebook iOS SDK v4. Not sure the line you suggested is added to Facebook App's code or not. Let me further test.

Comment: Just tested. Yes, Facebook App intentionally called the line to clear up the clipboard. #facepalm problem didn't solve, but at least what is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
  // Save text

      UIPasteboard* board = [UIPasteboard
    pasteboardWithName:@"com.company.wtv" create:YES]; 
    board.persistent=YES; [board setValue:@"123456ccc"
    forPasteboardType:@"com.company.wtv.sharedValue"];

    // Retrive text

        UIPasteboard* board = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"com.company.wtv" create:YES];
        board.persistent=YES;
        NSData* result=nil;
        NSString*resultStr=nil;
        result =[board valueForPasteboardType:@"com.company.wtv.sharedValue"];
        resultStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];// I got resultStr containing
    123456ccc

        NSLog(@"key %@",resultStr);
```

Comment: Can you explain how does your code relate to the question?